Is it possible with Playwright to filter out only the visible elements in combination with a getBy locator?
I'm trying to make a locator based on a getBy locator that returns only the visible elements. Is this possible?
Chaining a getBy locator with visible=true doesn't work: getByRole('textbox') >> visible=true
And the documentation doens't show a visible filter option, for the getBy locators. I'm I missing something?

The documentation is clear. You can identify only visible elements . Please share more details or stacktrace.

Apperently a getBy selector does filter out the not visible elements automatically. So if you have 2 input fields of type=text and only one is visible, then getByRole('textbox') only selects the visible textbox.

Please share more details, preferably a [mcve] and provide context for why you want to do this--what are you hoping to achieve?

@ggorlen As you can see I've answered my own question. getBy locators return only visible elements.

Feel free to post a self answer.

As suggested here, you can filter out not visible fields using this:
page.getByText('Waiting for response...', { exact: true }).locator('visible=true');

